# Reverse for 'order_detail' with keyword arguments '{'order_id': 'JUQEDJA6QQ'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: django, django-models

Can't understand the problem. Here is my models and urls file.

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = OrderManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.order_id

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('order_detail', kwargs={'order_id': self.order_id})
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import (OrderListView, OrderDetailView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('order/list/', OrderListView.as_view(), name='order_list'),
    path('order/<int:order_id>/', OrderDetailView.as_view(), name='order_detail'),
]
```

template.html

```
{% for order in order_list %}
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
            <td><a href="{{ order.get_absolute_url }}">{{ order.order_id }}</a></td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Error

> NoReverseMatch at /order/list/ Reverse for 'order_detail' with keyword
>   arguments '{'order_id': 'JUQEDJA6QQ'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['order\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']

Comment: The `order_id` is `JUQEDJA6QQ` but your URL only allows an `int` as `order_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your URL allows only `int`s as `id`s:

```
path('order/<int:order_id>/', OrderDetailView.as_view(), name='order_detail')
```

So here `JUQEDJA6QQ` can not be used in this URL.

We can let the URL accept strings, like:

```
path('order/<str:order_id>/', OrderDetailView.as_view(), name='order_detail')
```

In the `OrderDetailView`, you need to do proper filtering:

```
class OrderDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Order

    def get_queryset(self, *ags, **kwargs):
        return super(OrderDetailView, self).get_queryset(
            *args, *kwargs
        ).filter(order_id=self.kwargs['order_id'])
```

Answer (score 2):

"JUQEDJA6QQ" is not an int, it is a string.

```
path('order/<str:order_id>/', ...
```